# Need to use the internationalization for the column title

Tags: angular7, datatables-1.10

I want to  use the internationalization for the column title, But i could not find the proper solution.

I am using angular datatable, i have initialized the columns in ngOnInIt() as shown in the code:

```
ngOnInit(){

this.model.columns = [{
  title: 'xyz',  // **Need to use the internationalization for the column title ** 
  data: 'XYZ',
  render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return data === null ? '-' : data
      }
}],

}
```